# buliding a cython code as a module vs package on windows with visual studio compiler - symbosls not found in the package

Tags: windows, visual-studio, package, cython, setup.py

I have an issue with getting cython variables "exported to a module when used as a package .

The structure is the following:

```
test\
     setup.py
     mylib\
           mylib.pxd
           mylib.pyx
```

The setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension

ext_modules = [
    Extension(name="mylist",
              sources=["mylist/mylist.pyx"],
              libraries=[],
              extra_compile_args=["-w"]),
]

setup(
    name="mylist",
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules,                            
                            compiler_directives={'language_level': 3})
                            )
```

if I build the module with

```
 python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get

```
Compiling mylist/mylist.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing mylist/mylist.pyx
running build_ext
building 'mylist' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /Tcmylist/mylist.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist/mylist.obj -w
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
mylist.c
creating C:\MECP\WebGnome\cython-test\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_mylist build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist/mylist.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd ->
```

in the directory structure:

```
test\
     build\ 
           ...
     setup.py
     mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd*
     mylib\
           mylist.pxd
           mylist.pyx
           mylist.c
```

It I run the code:

```
from mylist import MyList

a = MyList()
a.append("apple")
a.append("banana")
a.append("tomato")
a.append("pear")
a.pop(2)#one of these fruit is not like the others...
print(a.get_data())
```

I get

```
['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
```

So far so good cython works fine and symbols are found in the python module.

However, if I want to do the exact thing in a package (put **init**.py) symbols are not found in the python package: (**init**.py is empty)

The structure is the following:

```
test\
     setup.py
     mylib\
           __init__.py  
           mylib.pxd
           mylib.pyx
```

and the setup.py needs to be changed to create a package

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools.extension import Extension
#from distutils.core import Extension

ext_modules = [
    Extension(name="mylist.mylist", 
              sources=["mylist/mylist.pyx"], 
              libraries=[], 
              extra_compile_args=["-w"]),
]
setup(
    name="mylist",
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules,
                            compiler_directives={'language_level': 3})
)
```

by doing

```
$  python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling mylist/mylist.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing mylist/mylist.pyx
running build_ext
building 'mylist.mylist' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\include -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt /Tcmylist/mylist.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist/mylist.obj -w
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
mylist.c
creating C:\MECP\WebGnome\cython-test\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
creating C:\MECP\WebGnome\cython-test\build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mylist
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:C:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Python310 /LIBPATH:C:\MECP\WebGnome\WebGnomeEnv\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x64 /EXPORT:PyInit_mylist build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist/mylist.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.lib
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mylist\mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd -> mylist
```

the new directory structure becomes:

```
test\
     build\ 
           ...
     setup.py
     mylib\
           mylist.cp310-win_amd64.pyd*
           mylist.pxd
           mylist.pyx
           mylist.c
```

running the same code as above gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MECP\WebGnome\cython-test\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mylist import MyList
ImportError: cannot import name 'MyList' from 'mylist' (C:\MECP\WebGnome\cython-test\mylist\__init__.py)
```

My questions are:

- What is needed in the **init**.py  to include the MyList symbols from cython.
- I tried with `__init__.pyx` and I had the same problem.
- Are there any special link flags needed to export from a package (a directory with `__init__.py_`)

I need to be a package because this is only a simplified test for a bigger project. Thank you for and help.

**Update:** if it makes a difference I put the content of the `.pxd` and `.pyx` files below:

mylist.pyx

```
cdef class MyList:

    def __cinit__(self):#__cinit__ is preferred for cdef class constructors
        self._base_list = []

    cpdef append(self, object item):
        self._base_list = self._base_list + [item]

    cpdef pop(self, int index=-1):
        self._base_list.pop(index)

    cpdef get_data(self):
        return self._base_list
```

mylist.pxd:

```
cdef class MyList:
    cdef public list _base_list
    cpdef append(self, object item)
    cpdef pop(self, int index=*)#Note: * is used in place of default values
    cpdef get_data(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found the answer.

I included `from .mylist import *` in `__init__.py` and I get the same behaviour as I was getting when I did not have a directory for the package.

and now I can do `from mylist import MyList` with no errors.

Please let me know if this is the right way of doing it or if there are better ways. Thanks